# How do I know why a certain Jar was added to my project?

Tags: java, maven

Is there a way to enter a single jar name to maven and get the full path of jars that added it to my project?

Comment: It is why or when? It's completely changing the meaning of question.

Comment: The only thing you can do is to analyse the history in your version control and see when the dependency is added...there might be relation to a change in your software...and hopefully there is a good log message which describes that...otherwise the why can't be answered via this..only the when....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best thing that you can do is using the [`mvn dependency:tree` command](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html).
It doesn't display the full path of jars that pulled the dependencies.
Instead, it displays the dependency tree for the current Maven project. 
You could so know for each resolved dependency the Maven module/dependency that pulled that.

Make the mapping between a dependency identified by the trio `groupId-artifactId-version` and your local repository should be so very simple.

Here is an example with a project that among other things has `jmh` as dependency :

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ map-benchmark ---
[INFO] davidxxx:map-benchmark:jar:1.0
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.7:test
[INFO] +- org.openjdk.jmh:jmh-core:jar:1.19:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:jar:4.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar:3.2:compile
[INFO] \- org.openjdk.jmh:jmh-generator-annprocess:jar:1.19:compile
```

You can see for example that `junit` is not a transitive dependency as it pulled by the current project itself.
But you could also see that `commons-math3` is a transitive dependency pulled by `jopt-simple` itself pulled by `jmh-core`.

The `dependency:tree` goal can also be used to filter only specific dependencies.

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=org.apache.commons:commons-math3
```

or (note `:` without prefix if we don't need to specify the groupId) :

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=:commons-math3
```

will output :

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ map-benchmark ---
[INFO] davidxxx:map-benchmark:jar:1.0
[INFO] \- org.openjdk.jmh:jmh-core:jar:1.19:compile
[INFO]    \- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar:3.2:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

This plugin can [help to solve conflicts](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html).
Here is a relevant example from the documentation.

For example, to find out why Commons Collections 2.0 is being used by
the Maven Dependency Plugin, we can execute the following in the
project's directory:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=commons-collections
```

The verbose flag instructs the dependency tree to display conflicting
dependencies that were omitted from the resolved dependency tree. In
this case, the goal outputs:

```
[INFO] [dependency:tree]
[INFO] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:maven-plugin:2.0-alpha-5-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-impl:jar:2.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |        \- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:2.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.0)
[INFO] \- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-site-renderer:jar:1.0-alpha-8:compile
[INFO]    \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-velocity:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO]       \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:2.0:compile
```

Answer (score 2):

Check

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/filtering-the-dependency-tree.html

You can search for an specific artifact using this maven command:

`mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=DESIRED-groupId:DESIRED-artifactId`

Also, if you use eclipse and the m2eclipse plugin (http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org) then there is a graphical version of dependency tree which will help you to filter it by jar name. See: https://books.sonatype.com/m2eclipse-book/reference/dependencies-sect-analyze-depend.html

There should be similar features in other IDEs